# Pass variable to item in paypal-checkout

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I started working with angular almost a whole week ago. And to make things easy I am trying to implement a paypal-checkout.

The checkout works fine, as long as I only pass the total amount. But I would like to pass several items to paypal.

I tried it this way:

```js
    import {
      Component,
      OnInit,
      ViewChild,
      Input,
      ElementRef,
      Output,
      EventEmitter
    } from "@angular/core";

    declare var paypal;

    @Component({
      selector: "app-payme",
      templateUrl: "./payme.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./payme.component.scss"]
    })
    export class PaymeComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild("paypal", { static: true }) paypalElement: ElementRef;
      @Input() total: number;
      @Input() cart: [];

      //payCart: [];

      @Output() isPaidFor: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

      paidFor = false;

      constructor() {}

      cartInConsole() {
        console.log("PayPalTotal", this.total);
      }

      declareItem() {
        let paypalItem = [];
        for (let i =0 ; i< this.cart.length; i++) {
            let currency = "EUR";
            let quantity = this.cart[i].selectedSize;
            let name = this.cart[i].name;
            let amount = this.cart[i].selectedPrice;
            console.log("DeclareFunction rennt");
            //let pushItem = {"quantity": quantity};  
            paypalItem.push({"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "EUR","value": currency, "amount": amount},"quantity": quantity,"name": name});
           console.log("Declare", paypalItem) 
            return paypalItem
          }

         console.log("StackOverFow", paypalItem )
      };


      ngOnInit() {
        console.log("PayPalCart", this.cart);
        this.declareItem();
        paypal
          .Buttons({
            createOrder: (data, actions) => {
              return actions.order.create(

                {
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    currency_code: 'EUR',
                    value: this.total,

                    }
                },
              items: this.paypalItem
            }]
            },
            onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
              const order = await actions.order.capture();
              this.paidFor = true;
              this.isPaidFor.emit(this.paidFor);
              console.log("Order", order);
            }
          })
          .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
      }

    }
```

But all I get as a response is: items is not defined.

The console.log of my paypalItem looks okay - it seems to be an array of object, just like it should be.

But how do I get it to pass that object to item or  item?

By the way: which one is it? Item or items? A few hours of googling an getting all different answers, makes you doubt anything :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE**

I tried declaring paypalItem and then setting in the declareItem-function. Unfortunately with the same result...

The code now looks like this:

```
 import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  ElementRef,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from "@angular/core";

declare var paypal;

@Component({
  selector: "app-payme",
  templateUrl: "./payme.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./payme.component.scss"]
})
export class PaymeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("paypal", { static: true }) paypalElement: ElementRef;
  @Input() total: number;
  @Input() cart: [];
paypalItem: [];
  //payCart: [];

  @Output() isPaidFor: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  paidFor = false;

  constructor() {}

  cartInConsole() {
    console.log("PayPalTotal", this.total);
  }

  declareItem() {
    let paypalItem = [];
    for (let i =0 ; i< this.cart.length; i++) {
        let currency = "EUR";
        let quantity = this.cart[i].selectedSize;
        let name = this.cart[i].name;
        let amount = this.cart[i].selectedPrice;
        console.log("DeclareFunction rennt");
        //let pushItem = {"quantity": quantity};  
        paypalItem.push({"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "EUR","value": currency, "amount": amount},"quantity": quantity,"name": name});
       console.log("Declare", paypalItem) 
        this.paypalItem = paypalItem;
      }

     console.log("StackOverFow", paypalItem )
  };


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("PayPalCart", this.cart);
    this.declareItem();
    paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create(

            {
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                currency_code: 'EUR',
                value: this.total,

                }
            },
          items: this.paypalItem
        }]
        },
        onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await actions.order.capture();
          this.paidFor = true;
          this.isPaidFor.emit(this.paidFor);
          console.log("Order", order);
        }
      })
      .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
  }

}
```

Any other ideas?

**One more update:**

Full code is on [codesandbox](https://www.codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-breeze-m5cyz)

Comment: mate you trying to access this.paypalItem. it is never declared somewhere on the class level, so how would u want to get a reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing a varaible declared as `paypalItem` in the class. Declare a variable called `paypalItem`, then inside method `declareItem()` assign the paypalItem array to the class level `paypalItem` you declared before.

```js
declareItem() {
...
this.paypalItem = paypalItem;
}
```

**Update**

It was a fault of your model binding. Paypal create order expects model with different required properties when you add items. I have added a sample model in the code. You can map your values to your model and replace it over there.

For testing, replace this code snippet over yours in the sandbox. Will work fine.

Refer this. [api documentation for create (items array)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item)

```js
 paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
          return actions.order.create({
            intent: "CAPTURE",
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "EUR",
                  value: "0.02",
                  breakdown: {
                    item_total: {
                      currency_code: "EUR",
                      value: "0.02"
                    }
                  }
                },
                items: [
                  {
                    name: "item1",
                    unit_amount: {
                      currency_code: "EUR",
                      value: "0.01"
                    },
                    quantity: "1"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "item2",
                    unit_amount: {
                      currency_code: "EUR",
                      value: "0.01"
                    },
                    quantity: "1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
          });
        }
      })
      .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

Comment: I tried that, but still with the same result... items is not defined, allthough a console.log shows the object.

Comment: move `this.paypalItem = paypalItem;` out of the for loop. does `console.log("StackOverFow", paypalItem )` logs the array?

Comment: Else remove declaring`let paypalItem = []` and `this.paypalItem = paypalItem;` in declare(). use `this.paypalItem.push()` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers... I tried all your suggestions, but the error still remains. I am not sure if it's the built array that is causing the error or if it's something else.If I try to this.paypalItem.push(), the paypal-buttons won't even show on the page. If I move this.paypalItem = paypalItem out of the loop, a console.log for this.paypalItem returns Object => Object0 =>Amount[Object] =>Quantity, Name. All of them with the correct keys and values... I am completely lost now....

Comment: If you can upload your code to https://stackblitz.com/ will be able to help you :)

Comment: Is codesandbox alright? That would save me the hassle of uploading everything to stackblitz => https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-breeze-m5cyz